# Is there any way to add arguments to a command in the Nuclide debugger in atom?

Tags: node.js, debugging, atom-editor, nuclide-editor, node-debugger

I've been trying to get the Nuclide debugger set up in atom. I've installed the `atom-ide-ui` and  `atom-ide-debugger-node` packages, and can see and open the Nuclide debugger. However, I want to run `yarn test_shared` as my command, but the debugger only seems to allow a one word command like `node` or `yarn`, without any arguments.

Running this would work, but won't actually run my test suite:
[image: Nuclide debuggger]

This is the command I want to run, but when I launch the debugger it throws this error: `Failed to start debugger process: Attribute 'runtimeExecutable' does not exist ('{path}').`
[image: Nuclide debugger]

Has anyone else found a way to set this up?